# How to compile .pyx using cythonize inside setup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython

Given a directory structure:

```
projectroot/
    docs/
    project/
        __init__.py
        core/
            __init__.py
            another.pyx
            anotherone.pyx
            lib/
                __init__.py
                something.pyx
    tests/
        mytest.py
    setup.py
```

And `setup.py` containing the following:

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize

try:
    from setuptools import Extension, setup, find_packages
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import Extension, setup, find_packages

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        name='myproject',
        version='1.0.0',
        packages=find_packages(),
        ext_modules=cythonize([
             Extension('*', ['project/core/lib/*.pyx']),
             Extension('*', ['project/core/*.pyx'])
        ])
    )
```

It compiles properly. The only problem is that when I open the python interpreter from the `root directory`, it raises an `ImportError`.

```
(test) [root@mico projectroot]# python
>>> from project.core.lib.another import AnotherClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named another
```

But when I open the interpreter inside any other directory, it works.

```
(test) [root@mico projectroot/project]# python
>>> from project.core.lib.another import AnotherClass
# no error
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: did you literally `import another.pyx` or did you `import another`?

Comment: @NilsWerner `import project.core.another`

Comment: Are the `.so` files generated at all? Also, I would recommend individual `Extension('project.core.lib.something', ['project/core/lib/something.pyx'])` entries instead of asterisks.

Comment: @NilsWerner Upon checking, the `.so` files are generated properly inside the `build/` folder. I updated the question. Can you please take a look? Thanks!

Comment: how did you run `setup.py`? did you do `pip install -e .`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the root directory, python tries to import from the local path first, i.e. it goes looking inside project/core.

I think you probably installed the package globally (in `/usr/lib/pythonx.y/dist-packages`), so it will work everywhere except in the root directory because the .so will not be present in `project/core`.

With any other current directory, python will go get the .so from its global folder in `/usr/lib/pythonx.y/dist-packages`, where you installed it.
To use it locally you need to do for instance `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, or `pip install -e .` in the root directory as Nils Werner mentioned.